# Angular 7 router not loading components

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Working 1st angular app (angular 7)and it is a slow go. Have a responsive navbar being displayed, and a ngx-mapbox map is the main screen. App will be used to track assets as they are moving on the map. Trying to get the 'settngs' component to display on top of the map so the user can configure some common preferences. But the component does not display. When I click on the settings icon, it changes color to show its active, so I know that much is working, but the component is not displayed nor is any error generated. Looking at the routing tree with Augury, it shows the components as being part of the routing tree.
Heirarchy is as follows:
app -
    - map (default display)
    - settings (display on top of map)
    - about (display on top of map)
    - login/logout (open form that will be used for Azure authentication)
    - and will add others as I develop

Here is app.component.html:

```
<app-navbar >
  <app-map></app-map>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-navbar>
```

Navbar html is the following:

```
<div style="height: 100vh;">

  <mat-toolbar color="primary">

    <span class="lg-view" fxHide.lt-md>
      <b class="cawg">CAWG</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <b class="cawg-header">T</b><span class="cawg-text">racking and </span>
      <b class="cawg-header">R</b><span class="cawg-text">emote&nbsp;</span>
      <b class="cawg-header">A</b><span class="cawg-text">ircraft&nbsp;</span> 
      <b class="cawg-header">C</b><span class="cawg-text">ommunication&nbsp;</span>
      <b class="cawg-header">S</b><span class="cawg-text">ystem (TRACS) </span>
      <span class="cawg-text">3.0</span>
      </span>
      <span class="sm-view" fxHide.gt-sm>
        <b class="cawg-text">TRACS3</b>
      </span>

    <span class="flex-spacer"></span>

    <div fxShow="true" fxHide.lt-md="true">

      <!-- The following menu items will be hidden on both SM and XS screen sizes -->

      <button mat-icon-button class="d-none d-sm-inline" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
        <button mat-menu-item>
          <mat-icon>airplanemode_active</mat-icon>
          <span>Real-time Tracking</span>
        </button>
        <button mat-menu-item>
          <mat-icon svgIcon="historical-tracking-black-48-inactive" style="color: black"></mat-icon>
          <span>Historical Tracking</span>
        </button>
        <button mat-menu-item>
          <mat-icon>grid_on</mat-icon>
          <span>Display Grids</span>
        </button>
        <button mat-menu-item>
          <mat-icon>airplanemode_inactive</mat-icon>
          <span>Stop Tracking</span>
        </button>
        <button mat-menu-item>
          <mat-icon>grid_off</mat-icon>
          <span>Grids Off</span>
        </button>
    </mat-menu>
    <button mat-icon-button  class="d-none d-sm-inline">
        <a [routerLink]="'/settings'"><mat-icon>settings</mat-icon></a>
    </button>
    <button mat-icon-button routerLink="chat" class="d-none d-sm-inline">
      <mat-icon>chat_bubble_outline</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <button mat-icon-button routerLink="reportIssue" class="d-none d-sm-inline">
      <mat-icon>bug_report</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <button mat-icon-button routerLink="about" class="d-none d-sm-inline">
      <mat-icon>info</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <button mat-button routerLink="login" class="nav-button">
      Sign In
    </button>

    </div>

    <div fxShow="true" fxHide.gt-sm="true">

      <a href="#" (click)="sidenav.toggle()"><mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon" >menu</mat-icon></a>

    </div>

  </mat-toolbar>

  <mat-sidenav-container fxFlexFill class="example-container">

    <mat-sidenav #sidenav fxLayout="column">

      <div fxLayout="column">


        <mat-nav-list>
          <mat-list-item >
          <mat-icon>airplanemode_active</mat-icon>
          <a matLine href="#" >Real-Time Tracking</a>
        </mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item >
          <mat-icon svgIcon="historical-tracking-black-48" style="color: black;"></mat-icon>
          <a matLine href="#" >Historical Tracking</a>
        </mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item >
            <mat-icon>grid_on</mat-icon>
            <a matLine href="#" >Display Grids</a>
        </mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item >
            <mat-icon>airplanemode_inactive</mat-icon>
            <a matLine href="#" >Stop Tracking</a>
        </mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item >
            <mat-icon>grid_off</mat-icon>
            <a matLine href="#" >Grids Off</a>
        </mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item>
          <mat-icon>settings</mat-icon>
          <a matLine routerLink="settings" >Settings</a> 
        </mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item>
          <mat-icon>chat_bubble_outline</mat-icon>
          <a matLine href="#" >Toggle Chat Window</a> 
        </mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item>
          <mat-icon>bug_report</mat-icon>
          <a matLine href="#" >Report Issue</a>
        </mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item>
          <mat-icon>info</mat-icon>
          <a matLine href="#" >About</a>
        </mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item>
          <a matLine href="#" >Sign In</a>
        </mat-list-item>
        </mat-nav-list>

      </div>

    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav-content fxFlexFill><ng-content></ng-content>></mat-sidenav-content>

  </mat-sidenav-container>

</div>
```

Map is pretty simple:

```
<div  fxFlexFill class="map">

  <mgl-map
      [style]="'mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v9'"
      [zoom]="9"
      [center]="_center"
      (load)="loadMap($event)"
  >
  </mgl-map> 
</div>
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
  import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
  import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

  import { routes } from './routes';
  import { SettingsContainerComponent } from '../components/settings-      container/settings-container.component';

  @NgModule({
    declarations: [],
  imports: [
     RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true }),
     CommonModule,
     SettingsContainerComponent
  ],
   exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

routes.ts:

```
import { Routes } from  '@angular/router';

import { DisplayMapComponent } from '../components/map/map.component';
import { SettingsContainerComponent } from '../components/settings-        container/settings-container.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'map',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: DisplayMapComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'settings', 
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: SettingsContainerComponent,
    data: { title: 'Settings' } 
  }
]
```

Settings is just a placeholder for now. settins-container.component.html:

```
<div fxFlexFill class="settigns-container">
      <h1>{{title}}</h1>
</div>>
```

and settings-container.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-settings-container',
  templateUrl: './settings-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./settings-container.component.scss']
})
export class SettingsContainerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('settings-contains init');
  }

}
```

If I move the  selector to above the map in the navbar, then the settings component is displayed above the map, but this is not what I want. I want the settings (and other components) to overlay the map when they are invoked. How do I acommplish this?

THanks.....

Comment: don't suppose you have this on a codeplayground like plunkr so we can interact with? Or github even?

Comment: Did you try out [CDK Overlay](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview)?

Comment: Have uploaded the entire project to https://github.com/cpeddie/TRACS3

Comment: @CrhistianRamirez- does the github project help any?

Comment: I think you should create one more component for "Map" that will be your home component that have background map in html and other component will inject using their selector so every selector component will have the background map.